# PayPal payout with paypal_id as a recipient

Tags: paypal

According to PayPal documentation when making a payout I can use unencrypted email (EMAIL), unencrypted phone number (PHONE), or encrypted PayPal account number (PAYPAL_ID) to specify a recipient.

How can I get the paypal_id (with a mobile sdk and a server using REST API for example)?
Will I get it encrypted and, if not, how should I encrypt it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get it by calling GetTransactionDetails API on an existing transaction. This API gives you the PAYERID, which is a 13 single-byte alphanumeric characters.

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/GetTransactionDetails_API_Operation_NVP/

There may be some business scenarios that you may want to get the PAYERID from previous transactions. But I agree, EMAIL would be much more straightforward.

Comment: What if I want to use paypal for payouts only and have no existing transactions? And what if the user changes account email, should I request user information each time before a payout?

Comment: If so, call the API using the user's email address, and the email address should be provided by the user. I've seen big websites doing this way. The risk is, you never know if the email provided is a real PayPal user, and if it is the PayPal user the user really uses if the s/he makes a typo.

Comment: But a good thing is, if the email is not a registered PayPal user, the money will be "hanging" there for some time, and the user can use the email to register PayPal to claim it. On the other hand, I've personally tried to find a way to check if a user is a PayPal user, but this has been fruitless so far. But maybe you could check on this API: GetVerifiedStatus